# How to handle RingCentral OAuth 2.0 "Invalid application" TokenInvalid error

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, ringcentral

When using a OAuth 2.0 Bearer token with the following cURL command and receiving the following error, what does the `TokenInvalid` "Invalid application" error mean and how to handle this error? The application is valid in the Developer Portal and the same token is working for other API calls in an running app.

**cURL Request**

```
curl -XGET https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~ \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <my_token>'
```

**Response**

```
401 Unauthorized

{
  "errorCode" : "TokenInvalid",
  "message" : "Invalid application",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "OAU-127",
    "message" : "Invalid application"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RingCentral operates different API environments that use different application definitions (client ids and secrets). A token and application that is valid in one environment may not be valid in another.

A common reason this error can occur is when a token or application is only valid in the sandbox environment is being used in the production environment. For example, this error will be encountered when making a request to the production environment (https://platform.ringcentral.com) with a token intended for the sandbox environment (https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com).